# Nuxt.js: Access static directory from Vue plugin: '~/static/media'

Tags: plugins, vue.js, directory, assets, nuxt.js

I am using [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org) and with this [image lazyload plugin](https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload)

This works great, but now I want to use some options of the plugin, like a custom loader image.

The code would look like this in my nuxt plugin file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'

const options = {
  preLoad: 1.3,
  loading: '~/static/media/loader.svg',
  attempt: 1,
  // the default is ['scroll', 'wheel', 'mousewheel', 'resize', 'animationend', 'transitionend']
  listenEvents: [ 'scroll' ]
}

Vue.use(VueLazyload, options)
```

In the plugins docs there is an example using a path like this:
`loading: 'dist/loading.gif',`

But I want to see the loading not only after I generated a dist folder, I want to see in locally.

So my question is:
How would I set paths in a Vue plugin file to make them work locally and after nuxt generate?

As an example: in CSS files you can set `url('~/static/…PATH')`

I have not found anything here:
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/
nor here
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets

Comment: How about loading : require('~/static/media/loader.svg')

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aldarund correctly proposed

`loading: require('~/static/media/loading.svg'),`
works perfectly.
Thanks